# gnu make, include path for `include` directives

Tags: makefile, include, include-path

Apart from the standard directories used by make to locate files loaded by `include` directives, is there any way to specify additional include paths within the `makefile` itself? I'm aware of the `-I` command-line GNU make option but I would like to know if there's any make variable to specify the same.

Answer (score 1):

I suggested using the `.INCLUDE_DIRS` variable, but as pointed out in the comment below, that variable is read-only.

The only other way I can think of is to have a top-level file invoke the real makefile, and have the top level one update `MAKEFLAGS`:

```
# Top level -- Call it GNUmakefile?
INCLUDE_DIRS := first second third
MAKEFLAGS += $(foreach dir,$(INCLUDE_DIRS),--include-dir=$(dir))
.DEFAULT all:;$(MAKE) -f Makefile $(MAKECMDGOALS)
```

Then the real `Makefile` is invoked with the three directories in `.INCLUDE_DIRS`.

Comment: Yeah I've already discovered that, but modifying that variable causes no effect. The `INCLUDE_DIRS` variable just contain a hardcoded list of include directories to inform you what will GNU Make use.